# Difference between SqlDataReader.Read and SqlDataReader.NextResult

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

What is the main difference between these two methods? On the msdn website it is explained like below but I don't understand it.

`Read` Advances the SqlDataReader to the next record. (Overrides
DbDataReader.Read().)

`NextResult` Advances the data reader to the next
result, when reading the results of batch Transact-SQL statements. (Overrides dbDataReader.NextResult().)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If your statement/proc is returning multiple result sets, For example, if you have two  `select` statements in single `Command` object, then you will get back two result sets.

- `NextResult` is used to move between result sets.
- `Read` is used to move forward in records of a single result set.

Consider the following example:

If you have a proc whose main body is like:

```
.... Proc start

SELECT Name,Address FROM Table1

SELECT ID,Department FROM Table2

-- Proc End
```

Executing the above proc would produce two result sets.  One for `Table1` or first select statement and other for the next `select` statement.

By default first result set would be available for `Read`. If you want to move to second result set, you will need `NextResult`.

See: [Retrieving Data Using a DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx)

Example Code from the same [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx): Retrieving Multiple Result Sets using NextResult

```
static void RetrieveMultipleResults(SqlConnection connection)
{
    using (connection)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
          "SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM dbo.Categories;" +
          "SELECT EmployeeID, LastName FROM dbo.Employees",
          connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.HasRows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", reader.GetName(0),
                reader.GetName(1));

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", reader.GetInt32(0),
                    reader.GetString(1));
            }
            reader.NextResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with 2 `select` statements in one query. If you have 2 `select` statements, this means that you have 2 queries... EDIT: Ok, I think I understand now. NextResult moves to the next 'query' in your example actually. This happens only when you use procedures?

Comment: @Ozkan, You can execute multiple select statement in a single command like `SELECT * FROM Table1;SELECT * FROM TABLE2;`, separated by `;` in case of SQL , or you can have stored procedure with multiple select statements.

Comment: @Ozkan, to your edit in comment, no you can concatenate two queries as well in a command. I have added a link from MSDN and example from there as well.

Comment: Thanks, It should be better if name is NextResultSet :)

Answer (score 4):

Not strictly an answer to this question but if you use the DataTable.Load method to consume data from the reader rather than Reader.Read note that after the Load method has completed, the reader is now placed at the start of the next result set so you should not call the NextResult method otherwise you will skip the next resultset.

A simple loop on Reader.HasRows around a DataTable.Load call is all that you need to process potential multiple resultsets in this scenario.