# C# ,mysql ,how to select and read all data from one table?

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to select and show( let's say in Debug console) all data from one table which is in MySQL database.

I can read data using column names or indexes, but only in one fetched row.
Can somebody tell me how to loop trough rows? So I can read it's data..

Thank you for any help.

```
public class DatabaseHandler
    {
      private bool query_status;
        private int? count;
        private DataTable data_table;
        private static MySqlConnection connection;
        private MySqlDataReader data_reader;
        private MySqlCommand command;
        private static DatabaseHandler databasehandler;
    public void insert(string table, Dictionary<string, string> data)...

    public void select(string columns, string table, string where)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            this.command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM user";
            this.data_reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (this.data_reader.HasRows) {
                this.count = data_reader.FieldCount;
                do
                {
                    this.data_reader.NextResult();
                    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(this.data_reader.GetValue(i));
//only returns one row. How to view all data?
                    }
                }
                while (this.data_reader.Read());           
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
    public void delete(string table, string where)...
    public void update(string table, string new_data, string where)... 
    public bool get_query_status()...
    public string get_custom_string()...
    public int? get_query_count()...
    public DataTable get_result()...
```

Comment: is your count returning the actual number of entries in the database or does it only = 1? check that first I would say. 
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(this.data_reader.GetValue(i));
                        Debug.WriteLine(count);
                    }

Comment: Now I know where I made mistake. When fetching results , I used   DB.select("*", "table_name", "id = ''1"); instead of DB.select("*", "table_name", "") So I always fetched only one.. I did not pay attention to this line of code at all. My fault. Thanks for help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The FieldCount() returns the number of **columns** in the table. I think your table has only 1 column, which is why it is not iterating through the rest of the records.

I suggest you remove the usage of the count variable and just go with the boolean returned from the Read() method.

Answer (score 2):

You can access database records sequentially by using [`DataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
try
{
    connection.Open();
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM User", connection);
    using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // access your record colums by using reader
            Console.WriteLine(reader["COLUMN_NAME"]);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // handle exception here
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

Or you can use [`DataAdapter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxkb3c3d(v=vs.110).aspx) to fill local `DataSet` or `DataTable` and loop your rows from there:

```
try
{
    connection.Open();
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM User", connection);
    DataTable data = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(data);
    foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(row["COLUMN_NAME"]);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

Also always remember to make sure that you close all active connections to your database.

Answer (score 1):

You are using NextResult, this will move to the next result set.

See [Difference between SqlDataReader.Read and SqlDataReader.NextResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27044485/difference-between-sqldatareader-read-and-sqldatareader-nextresult)

In your example if you change your code to be something like

```
this.data_reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (this.data_reader.HasRows) {
            this.count = data_reader.FieldCount;
            while (this.data_reader.Read());           
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(this.data_reader.GetValue(i));
                }
            }
           this.data_reader.Close();
        }
```

Comment: I have just tested that code here and it works fine on a test database. I assume you are not getting any exceptions when running?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to use MySqlDataAdapter:

```
 DataTable temp = new DataTable();
 adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
 adapter.Fill(temp);

 foreach(DataColumn column in  temp.Columns) 
 {
     foreach(DataRow row in temp.Rows)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(row[column]);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
try
{
    listView1.Items.Clear();
    MySqlConnection con = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("server=localhost;port=3306;uid=sql3305088;pwd=KwxUiLHnKt;database=sql3305088;");

    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand com = con.CreateCommand();

    com.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    com.CommandText = "SELECT * From eslamtarek";
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();


    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem();
            lv.Text = reader.GetString(0);
            lv.SubItems.Add(reader.GetString(1));
            lv.SubItems.Add(reader.GetString(2));
            lv.SubItems.Add(reader.GetString(3));
            lv.SubItems.Add(reader.GetString(4));
            listView1.Items.Add(lv);
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try in this way of coding

```
try
{

     DataTable data = new DataTable();

     connection.Open();
     MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM User", connection);
     data.load(command.ExecuteReader());

     foreach(Datarow row in data.rows)
     {
        // access your record colums by using reader
        Console.WriteLine(row["COLUMN NAME"]);
     }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     // handle exception here
}
finally
{
     connection.Close();
}
```