# Access Query on C# Not Generating Results

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, ms-access

I am using the following Access query on C# MVC to compare two tables and return records that fall within the date range and machine selected by the user. The query code runs perfectly on the actual Access database but I guess something is wrong with the connection string and the code to return the results. I am not sure what's wrong with the code and I would appreciate if someone could help me determine what's wrong. Thanks!

C# MVC Controller code:

```
    public ActionResult MissingChecksheets(string startDate, string endDate, string machine)
    {
        var query = $@"SELECT * FROM [TrackingLog]
                       WHERE [TrackingLog].[Workcenter] = '{machine}' AND 
                             [TrackingLog].[Complete Date] > #{startDate}# AND
                             [TrackingLog].[Complete Date] < #{endDate}# AND
                             [TrackingLog].[Order Item] NOT IN (SELECT [OrderNum] FROM [dbo_Checksheet])";

        var sheets = new List<Checksheet>();

        using (var con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Checksheets.accdb;"))
        {
            using (var command = new OleDbCommand(query, con))
            {
                con.Open();

                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.NextResult())
                    {
                        sheets.Add(new FabChecksheet
                        {
                            OrderNum = reader.GetString(0),
                            PartNum = reader.GetString(1)
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return PartialView(sheets);
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any erros?

Comment: You might try `while (reader.Read())` instead of .NextResult().

Comment: No, not any errors. But when I run the code, the OrderNum and PartNum columns are empty and no results are generated. However, when I paste the query code on MSAccess Database Query, there are records that are generated.

Comment: @CharlesMay That worked, Charles! Thank you so much!

Comment: From the tags for `access` - "DO NOT USE this tag for Microsoft Access, use `ms-access` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`OleDbDataReader.NextResult()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.nextresult(v=vs.110).aspx) method used to move between result set if the query string has multiple result sets (e.g. more than two `SELECT` statements, not counting `SELECT` inside aggregate functions). Since your query has single result set, [`OleDbDataReader.Read()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx) must be used to move between records:

```
using (var con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Checksheets.accdb;"))
{
    using (var command = new OleDbCommand(query, con))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Only single result set, use 'Read' here
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                sheets.Add(new FabChecksheet
                {
                    OrderNum = reader.GetString(0),
                    PartNum = reader.GetString(1)
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if `NextResult()` is used, the data reader will move to next result set which has empty data.

Related issue:

[Difference between SqlDataReader.Read and SqlDataReader.NextResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27044485/difference-between-sqldatareader-read-and-sqldatareader-nextresult)