# how to use multiple results in VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, navicat

I need to show in **3 textboxes the result of 3 queries made in the same statement.**

I have two tables called `personal_sueldos` and `personal_haberes` in mysql.
They both have the same columns. I need to select the same information from both in two queries, and the 3rd query is the subtraction of `descuentos` from `haberes`.
So I have to show all 3 results in 3 textbox in a VB.NET form.

Code of the query in MySql:

```sql
SELECT SUM(importe) FROM personal_haberes WHERE persona_doc = 55880334 AND mes = 11 AND año = 2019;

SELECT SUM(importe) FROM personal_descuentos WHERE persona_doc = 55880334 AND mes = 11 AND año = 2019;

SELECT (SELECT SUM(importe) FROM personal_haberes WHERE persona_doc = 
55880334 AND mes = 11 AND año = 2019) -
(SELECT SUM(importe) FROM personal_descuentos WHERE persona_doc = 
55880334 AND mes = 11 AND año = 2019) as importeTotal
```

Code in VB.NET:

```vb
cnn.Open()
Dim Query As String
Query = "SELECT SUM(importe) as ImporteHaberes FROM personal_haberes WHERE persona_doc  = " & Module1.document & " AND mes = " & HR_DatePicker.Value.Month & " AND año = " & HR_DatePicker.Value.Month & ";" & _
"SELECT SUM(importe) as ImporteDescuentos FROM personal_descuentos WHERE persona_doc = " & Module1.document & " AND mes = " & HR_DatePicker.Value.Month & " AND año = " & HR_DatePicker.Value.Month & ";" & _
"SELECT (SELECT SUM(importe) FROM personal_haberes WHERE persona_doc    = " & Module1.document & " AND mes = " & HR_DatePicker.Value.Month & " AND año = " & HR_DatePicker.Value.Month & ";) -" & _
"(SELECT SUM(importe) FROM personal_descuentos WHERE persona_doc = " & Module1.document & " AND mes = " & HR_DatePicker.Value.Month & " AND año = " & HR_DatePicker.Value.Month & ";) AS ImporteTotal"
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(Query, cnn)
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
While rdr.Read
    Me.HR_txtHaberes.Text = rdr.Item("ImporteHaberes").ToString
    Me.HR_txtDescuentos.Text = rdr.Item("ImporteDescuentos").ToString
    Me.HR_txtTotal.Text = rdr.Item("ImporteTotal").ToString
End While
cnn.Close()
```

I have to show the result of each query in a textbox.

Now VB gives me the error "Could not find specified column in results"

Comment: There are three results in your reader. You need to read the first, then go to the next result with _reader.NextResult_ and finally go to the third result, again with a NextResult call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between SqlDataReader.Read and SqlDataReader.NextResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27044485/difference-between-sqldatareader-read-and-sqldatareader-nextresult)

Comment: Said that, please read as soon as possible about Sql Injection. Your code is really open to this simple hack that could destroy your data

Comment: The code is for a project in my school and the teachers said that we mustn't worry about security because it wouldn't be in the internet

Comment: Your teacher is giving you a wrong habit. Never write code like that. And using a proper parameterized query would also easily revelead the typo error in your current code (You use Month also for the Year)

Comment: I didn't understand exactly how to use reader.NextResult.

Comment: I tried like this:

Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(Query, cnn)
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
   While rdr.Read
      Me.HR_txtHaberes.Text = rdr.Item("SUM(importe)").ToString 
   End While
rdr.NextResult()
   While rdr.Read
      Me.HR_txtDescuentos.Text = rdr.Item("SUM(importe)").ToString
   End While
rdr.NextResult()
   While rdr.Read
      Me.HR_txtTotal.Text = rdr.Item("ImporteTotal").ToString
   End While
cnn.Close()

But again the same error

Comment: @Steve I'm still stucked on it and idk how to proceed

Comment: [Edit the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58756322/edit) rather than adding code as comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a *lot* to clean up here. It's **never** okay to use string concatenation to build a query like that, *even in learning code*. This is also not the correct way to manage the connection object.

A better pattern (with fixed code, including the next result issue), looks like this:

```vb
'Multi-line string literals are now supported
' Note: there is NO CONCATENATION here. This is a constant.
' I also consolidated the SQL to avoid worrying about separate result sets.
Dim Query As String = "
    SELECT SUM(importe) as Importe
     FROM personal_haberes
     WHERE persona_doc = @document AND mes = @mes AND año = @ano
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUM(importe)
     FROM personal_descuentos
     WHERE persona_doc = @document AND mes = @mes AND año = @ano;"

Using cnn As New MySqlConnection("connection string here"), _
      cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, cnn)

    'Guessing at types/lengths here.
    ' Use the ACTUAL columns types and lengths from your database
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@document", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Module1.document
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@mes", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = HR_DatePicker.Value.Month
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ano", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = HR_DatePicker.Value.Year 'This was your error

    'Wait as long as possible to call .Open()
    cnn.Open()
    Using rdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        rdr.Read()
        Dim Haberes As Integer = CInt(rdr("Importe"))
        rdr.Read()
        Dim Descuentos As Integer = CInt(rdr("Importe"))

        Me.HR_txtHaberes.Text = Haberes.ToString()
        Me.HR_txtDescuentos.Text = Descuentos.ToString()
        Me.HR_txtTotal.Text = (Haberes - Descuentos).ToString() 'No need to make the database do the subtraction work.
    End Using
End Using ' This will take care of closing the connection.. even if an exception is thrown!
'The old code might have leaked open connections whenever there was an exception.
```

Comment: "'No need to make the database do the subtraction work." Not to mention that the original Select statement reruns the first 2 Selects duplicating the work.

Comment: It's funny that you say that concatenation mustn't be used at query bulding because our teacher forces us to concatenate and also is the way he taught us LOL

Comment: We could say that my school is stuck 1990. My teacher also say that he is obligated to taught us old technologies and other old stuff. Summing up he teach us wrong things. I hope that University will be a different thing...

Comment: @GuillermoCrucci Then your teacher taught you wrong. Google for "sql injection". You _can_ sometimes use string concatenation to assemble parts of a query, but **NOT** textbox fields supplied by a user. Those **MUST** be handled using parameterization. Anyone saying different is stuck in 1996. This is too important to even using for learning/proof of concept work. If you've advanced enough to learn to run SQL from code, you've advanced enough to learn parameters at the same time.

Comment: You should learn many things that are old. That is good. Much of what we do today is founded and still using technologies from the 80's and 90's behind the scenes. But SQL injection isn't something you mess around with.

Comment: You have reason mate... Now I have a new question and I searched it in internet but I didn't get any useful result. Could you help me again?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start changing your query to a parameterized one. Your teacher has told you that this is not important in your current context, but I strongly disagree. Writing parameterized query is a skill that you need to learn as soon as possible. A part from the security consideration, look at how clear is it now without all those concatenations.

```
Dim Query As String = "
    SELECT SUM(importe) as ImporteHaberes 
    FROM personal_haberes 
    WHERE persona_doc  = @doc AND mes = @mes AND año = @año;
    SELECT SUM(importe) as ImporteDescuentos 
    FROM personal_descuentos 
    WHERE persona_doc = @doc AND mes = @mes AND año = @año;
    SELECT  (SELECT SUM(importe) 
        FROM personal_haberes 
        WHERE persona_doc = @doc AND mes = @mes AND año = @año) -
            (SELECT SUM(importe) 
        FROM personal_descuentos 
        WHERE persona_doc = @doc AND mes = @mes AND año = @año) AS ImporteTotal"
```

Now create the command and add the three parameters
Again look at how it is more concise and clear and is easy to spot the problem with the Value.Month repeated also for the final parameter.

```
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(Query, cnn)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@doc", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Module1.document
cmd.Parameters.Add("@mes", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = HR_DatePicker.Value.Month
' ???? This should be HR_DatePicker.Value.Year ???? '
cmd.Parameters.Add("@año", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = HR_DatePicker.Value.Month
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

And now the usage of NextResult. Simply start your first loop to get the first result, then pass to the second result and so on

```
While rdr.Read()
    Me.HR_txtHaberes.Text = rdr.Item("ImporteHaberes").ToString
End While    
rdr.NextResult() 

While rdr.Read()
    Me.HR_txtDescuentos.Text = rdr.Item("ImporteDescuentos").ToString
End While
rdr.NextResult() 
While rdr.Read()
    Me.HR_txtTotal.Text = rdr.Item("ImporteTotal").ToString
End While
```

Given the fact that your return is always a single record for each query then you could also replace the While loop with a simple

```
If rdr.Read() Then
    Me.HR_txtHaberes.Text = rdr.Item("ImporteHaberes").ToString
End If
rdr.NextResult() 
.....
```