# Good query returning no results using DbContext with ADO.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, ado.net

I need to run the following query on my DB context.

```
SELECT u.[Email],
u.[EmailConfirmed],
u.[PhoneNumber],
STRING_AGG(r.[Name], ', ') AS Roles
FROM [AspNetUsers] u
LEFT OUTER JOIN [AspNetUserRoles] ur ON ur.UserId = u.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN [AspNetRoles] r ON r.Id = ur.RoleId
GROUP BY u.[Email], u.[EmailConfirmed], u.[PhoneNumber]
```

When I run this in the query window, I get four results. So I came up with the following code.

```
string UserQuery = @"SELECT u.[Email],
u.[EmailConfirmed],
u.[PhoneNumber],
STRING_AGG(r.[Name], ', ') AS Roles
FROM [AspNetUsers] u
LEFT OUTER JOIN [AspNetUserRoles] ur ON ur.UserId = u.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN [AspNetRoles] r ON r.Id = ur.RoleId
GROUP BY u.[Email], u.[EmailConfirmed], u.[PhoneNumber]";

var conn = DbContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
using var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = UserQuery;
DbContext.Database.OpenConnection();
using var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.NextResult())
{
    Users.Add(new UserViewModel
    {
        Email = (string)reader["Email"],
        EmailConfirmed = (bool)reader["EmailConfirmed"],
        Phone = (string)reader["PhoneNumber"],
        Role = (string)reader["Roles"]
    });
}
```

This code runs without error, but the first call to `reader.NextResult()` returns false!

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: Is your context pointing at the same DB?

Comment: You mean the same DB where the query worked? Yes, definitely. And the four results confirm that is the DB I'm working with.

Comment: It may be that the string is not properly escaped. Could you try this: https://pastebin.com/Z7KAY9mN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be `reader.Read()` as `reader.NextResult()` will bring back the next result *set*

See:

[Difference between SqlDataReader.Read and SqlDataReader.NextResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27044485/difference-between-sqldatareader-read-and-sqldatareader-nextresult)

Comment: Well don't I feel stupid. Guess I haven't worked with raw ADO.NET in a while.